# SQL reporting services beginner

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I am not clear with SQL reporting services. Can someone please give me a brief explanation or post some tutorial with examples and concept explanations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services):

> SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) is a server-based report generation software system from Microsoft. It can be used to prepare and deliver a variety of interactive and printed reports. It is administered via a web interface. Reporting services features a web services interface to support the development of custom reporting applications.

Check out [Google](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENCA358&=&q=sql+server+reporting+services&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=sql+server+reporting+&gs_rfai=) for more.  [This link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/beginning-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-part-1/) seems to have a good overview of how to get it setup.  [Codeplex](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/) has some sample code for reporting services.